# wrong jQuery window/screen width/height above 1600x900

Tags: javascript, jquery, screen-resolution

I get both window and screen dimensions like this:

```
$(window).load(function() {
var width = 0;
var height = 0;
var screen_width = 0;
var screen_height = 0;
width = $(window).width();
height = $(window).height();
screen_width = screen.width;
screen_height = screen.height;
});
```

Everything works fine in Chrome.
In Firefox and IE11 the dimensions go only up to 1600x900 max!
Screen width and height both max out and wont show me the right values for 1920x1080 screens.

e.g.:
Real window & screen dimensions = 1920x979 - 1920x1080

My script shows me in FF and IE11: 931x165 - 1600x900
(Only Chrome working fine)

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I get wrong values in FF and IE. I edited my post with an example.

Comment: Did you sort out the issue?

Comment: @Will: Thank your very much for your time. I can't repeat the error in other environments. So it has something todo with my very old HTML4 and CSS1 template. I need to stick with this template for now. A new html5 layout will be published in a few months. I will ignore the bug till then. Especially because there are not so many > 1600px pc screens.

Answer (score 0):

Sure your browser is maximized?

```
width = $(window).width();
height = $(window).height();
```

output the size of the browser window

```
screen_width = screen.width;
screen_height = screen.height;
```

output the size of the actual monitor.

I ran this in the console of FF and Chrome on my 1680x1050 monitor with both windows maximized:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var width = 0;
    var height = 0;
    var screen_width = 0;
    var screen_height = 0;
    width = $(window).width();
    height = $(window).height();
    screen_width = screen.width;
    screen_height = screen.height;
    console.log('width', width);
    console.log('height', height);
    console.log('screen_width', screen_width);
    console.log('screen_height', screen_height);
});
```

**Chrome:**
width 1665
height 952
screen_width 1680
screen_height 1050

**Firefox:**
width 1665
height 908
screen_width 1680
screen_height 1050

The values of the jquery checks will never hit the screen resolution due to browser chrome.